# Build Failure Analyzer Plugin does not find failure cause

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I've defined a failure cause, and when I "Match Text" against a build log, it matches.

But when I do a new build, I still no identified problems.

But still, when I match the failure cause against that new build, it matches.

What might I be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Does the build log match the failure cause if you scan all builds after they are finished?

In my case this has happened when the log line that would match the defined failure cause regex was output only after the Build Failure Analyzer has already run on the build. To check this, look if the log lines

```
[BFA] Scanning build for known causes...
[BFA] No failure causes found
[BFA] Done. 0s
```

are output before or after the log line.

Answer (score 0):

As the plugin name suggests, only "Failed builds" are analysed. If your job does not finish with UNSTABLE or FAILED, the logs will **not be scanned at all**, so it does not matter whether your Rules would match.

Also, the logs are scanned only once, after the job finishes, you can't force a scan on an old build.